# PDF Generator in jboss fuse

Tags: java, jboss, esb, itext7

I am trying to create a pdf file. Using itext 7 library to do so. It is created when I run code locally. But I get an exception when i deploy code on server and run that code through an api of ESB. I am using jboss fuse.
following is the exception that i get:

```
`<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /cxf/ecare/generatepdf. Reason:

            <pre>    Server Error</pre>
        </p>
        <h3>Caused by:</h3>
        <pre>org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-ecesb-dev01-46140-1536727471245-1041-2]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement
    at com.evampsaanga.jazz.service.PDFGeneratorService.generateHistoryPDF(PDFGeneratorService.java:133)
    at com.evampsaanga.jazz.controllers.PDFGeneratorController.GeneratePDF(PDFGeneratorController.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement not found by jazze-care-esb [335]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
</pre>
```

Comment: The message isn't clear `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement`?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement not found by jazze-care-esb - is com.itextpdf:layout on your classpath on the server?

Comment: @jens .. the exception that i am getting is placed as it is.

Comment: yes i have added itextpfd.layout jar in classpath

Comment: please Show which jar's are added to your classpath